# How to implement a tags feature for a post in a flask website using flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How to implement a tags feature for a post in a flask website using flask-sqlalchemy?

In my flask website, users can create posts. A post can have tags, which are used to define and summarise the type of content present inside a post.
For example, a post can have the 'action' and 'mystery' tags (there are no pre-defined tags at the moment).
As you might have observed in the previous example, one post can have multiple tags so I want to create such relationships between the tables. (if there will be any, as I will mention later)
I will be taking the input from the user as text from an input field of type "text" from the template where users can create posts.
How should I go about doing this? Should I create a new table called tags? If yes, what should its structure be like as per flask-sqlalchemy.
I am new to flask and web development in general so I don't know how to go about things that I have not done before :/
Here is the code for the table "post":

```
class Posts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    # post_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='Posts', passive_deletes=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='Posts', passive_deletes=True)
```

The user will enter the tags as text in the input field, each individual word is meant to be a tag which will be seprated by a space.
A good real life example of what I am trying to do would be the tags field in stack overflow or the tags in reddit.
Although both of those facilities have some pre defined tags, in reddit, you can choose from a plethora of tags which will be shown to you on the screen (it's not what I am trying to do).
In stack overflow, you first enter the tags as text (similar to what I am trying to do) and then you can select if what you wrote matches the pre determined tags on the site. (I will not implement the last part about pre determined tags though so it will be plain old text)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for can be done in many way. but I'm gonna show you the most efficient and simple way.

Add string tag to your model then create a method that returns a list of tags for a specific post.

```
class Posts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    # post_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='Posts', passive_deletes=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='Posts', passive_deletes=True)
     tags = db.Column(db.String(250))

     @property

     def tag_names(self) -> list:
         return self.tags.split()
```

I hope this helps. (my opinion)